# Dart: change "null" string to null while converting CSV file to List

Tags: flutter, csv, dart, sqflite

I open a CSV file and convert it to List class in flutter(Dart). Everything works well except null cells. The null cells convert in string type "null". I'm looking for an efficient way to change them as real null across converting. Here is my sample code:

```
//--- mytable.csv is an SQLite table

final myStream = File('mypath/mytable.csv').openRead();

final _myList = await myStream
        .transform(utf8.decoder)
        .transform(new CsvToListConverter())
        .toList();
```

Comment: What do you mean with "real null"? Can you give a short example data of what you currently have and what you expect?

Comment: Of course yes:
_myList[0][2] = "null" 
is the current value but i want to changes as follow:
_myList[0][2] = null while converting from Csv to current List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you want to turn `_myList[0][2] = "null"` into `_myList[0][2] = null`:

```
List<List<String?> nullify(Iterable<Iterable<String?>> mylist){
  return mylist.map(
    (list) => list.map(
      (field) => field=="null"?null:field)
    .toList())
  .tolist();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, dear Christian. Now my problem is solved as below statement.
final _myList = await myStream
        .transform(utf8.decoder)
        .transform(new CsvToListConverter())
        .map((list) => list.map((e) => e == "null" ? null : e).toList())
        .toList();